# Angular2 using YEOMAN generator doesn't run

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator, angular

I have started learning angular2 and created project using YEOMAN which creates all the necessary files and a simple running project.

But when i try to run it using gulp serve on web it throws error like

```
Potentially unhandled rejection [2] TypeError: Error loading "index" at http://localhost:8000/index.js
Cannot convert object to primitive value
    at http://localhost:8000/lib/system.js:1:4824
    at Array.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/lib/angular2.js:3888:7)
    at d (http://localhost:8000/lib/system.js:1:5501)
    at d (http://localhost:8000/lib/system.js:1:5364)
    at d (http://localhost:8000/lib/system.js:1:5364)
    at l (http://localhost:8000/lib/system.js:1:4590)
    at Object.$__global.upgradeSystemLoader.e.instantiate.Promise.all.then.execute (http://localhost:8000/lib/system.js:1:8278)
    at o (http://localhost:8000/lib/es6-module-loader.js:7:18496)
    at p (http://localhost:8000/lib/es6-module-loader.js:7:18868)
    at j (http://localhost:8000/lib/es6-module-loader.js:7:16406)
```

I don't have any idea about this error.
Can anybody help me regarding this to at least it runs.

I have tried with quick 5 min guide from :
https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html

```
Uncaught TypeError: angular2_1.Componant is not a function
es6-module-loader@0.16.6.src.js:140 Potentially unhandled rejection [2] Error loading "app" at http://localhost:8080/app.js
Error evaluating http://localhost:8080/app.js
Uncaught TypeError: angular2_1.Componant is not a function (WARNING: non-Error used)
```

Comment: `Componant`? That's a typo, it must be `Component`. The first issue seems to be configuration issues. You should post your configuration and everything related.

Comment: @EricMartinez I have written all the code from quick start document only nothing at my own at this stage. so i don't find its a mistake from my side. have you tried doing that with the same code which is present in that quick   guide.

Comment: Actually I did. Of course I had to change a few things. That's why I recommend you to post your configuration. Most likely you are missing something with Systemjs that is not being shown in the quickstart guide.

Comment: @EricMartinez in that case i don't have any config file. i have index.html , app.ts and app.js.
For system js i am adding it through https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js  as shown in quick start.

Can you provide me a basic project format on github.

Comment: Here's my basic project https://github.com/ericmartinezr/ng2-skeleton. There are another ways. This one for example [ng2-play.ts](https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/ng2-play.ts). You can choose whatever is easier for you.

Comment: Thanks @EricMartinez i ll look in to this soon

Comment: @EricMartinez your github code helped in running this. can you please provide me a link where i can get all the fundamentals  of each file used along with using it through gulp as you used in ng2-play.

Comment: the ng2-play is not mine, the first one link is mine. @MahaveerJain

Comment: @EricMartinez can you suggest me something to get started with this?

Comment: Getting started with that? Gulp? I haven't used it myself. Anyway I think that the official documentation should be the starting point.